# how to print the log file till a specific date

Tags: perl, scripting

I have cron log file with the format
current date is sep 22

**Sep 22 13:00:01 Hostname crond[24359]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)**

I want to print the log file till "sep 21" with the below format

```
date:time:user:command format
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
perl -pe 'exit if /^Sep 22/;' input.log
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open (my $IN,'<','foo.log') or die "$!";
while (<$IN>) {
    last if /^Sep 22/;
    print join(':',/^(\w{3}\s\d{1,2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+\((.+?)\) CMD \((.+?)\)/),"\n";
}
close $IN;
```

Same, one-liner flavor:

```
perl -nle "exit if /^Sep 22/;print join(':',/^(\w{3}\s\d{1,2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+\((.+?)\) CMD \((.+?)\)/)" foo.log
```

In case you want to be able to run your script again in the future, you can use the current day:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my (undef,undef,undef,$mday,$mon)=localtime(time);
my @abbr=qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);
open (my $IN,'<','foo.log') or die "$!";
while (<$IN>) {
    last if /^$abbr[$mon] $mday/;
    print join(':',/^(\w{3}\s\d{1,2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+\((.+?)\) CMD \((.+?)\)/),"\n";
}
close $IN;
```